# How do I preserve event listeners after sort?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating DOM elements then creating an array of JQuery objects with those DOM elements. After sorting the JQuery objects and re-appending them, the click event listener is gone. Is there a way to preserve the click listener?

```
for(var i=0; i<5; i++){
    var div = $('<div>',{
    id: i+"div",
    class: 'list-item '+i,
    html: "Item #"+i
  });
  div.data('i',i);
  $('.news-layout-1').append(div);
  div.on('click',function(){
    alert($(this).data('i'));
  }); 
}

$('.button').on('click',function(){
    var items = [];
  $('.news-layout-1').find('.list-item').each(function(index, item){
    items.push(item);
  });

  items = items.sort(function(a,b){
    var textA = $(a).html().toUpperCase();
    var textB = $(b).html().toUpperCase();
    return (textA > textB) ? -1 : (textA < textB) ? 1 : 0;
  });

  $('.news-layout-1').html('');

  for(var i=0; i<items.length; i++){
    $('.news-layout-1').append(items[i]);
  }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bhav4co6/5/

Comment: Please use Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) to put runnable demos **here**, on-site. Your question should be self-contained, including your HTML, which is currently just linked. Snippets avoid having that happen.

Comment: You can try delegating the listeners to the `$('body').on('click', '.button,'...)`  see: http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Comment: instead of $('.button').on('click',function(){ use $(document).on('click','.button',function(){

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're clearing the HTML, effectively removing the elements from the DOM, and they are just kept in memory, where they lose all associated data and events.

jQuery also uses `.empty()` internally when you do `.html("")` to make absolutely sure the elements, the data and the event listeners are removed.

If you just remove the line

```
$('.news-layout-1').html('');
```

you're fine, as the elements will just be moved, and keeps the event listeners

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var div = $('<div>', {
        id: i + "div",
        class: 'list-item ' + i,
        html: "Item #" + i
    });
    div.data('i', i);
    $('.news-layout-1').append(div);
    div.on('click', function() {
        alert($(this).data('i'));
    });
}

$('.button').on('click', function() {
    var items = [];
    $('.news-layout-1').find('.list-item').each(function(index, item) {
        items.push(item);
    });

    items = items.sort(function(a, b) {
        var textA = $(a).html().toUpperCase();
        var textB = $(b).html().toUpperCase();
        return (textA > textB) ? -1 : (textA < textB) ? 1 : 0;
    });

    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        $('.news-layout-1').append(items[i]);
    }
});
```

```css
.list-item { cursor: pointer }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="news-layout-1">
</div>
<a href="#" class="button btn">
  Sort
</a>
```

As a sidenote, there's no need for an array or a loop to append, you can just do

```
$('.button').on('click', function() {
    $('.news-layout-1 .list-item').sort(function(a, b) {
        var textA = $(a).html().toUpperCase();
        var textB = $(b).html().toUpperCase();
        return (textA > textB) ? -1 : (textA < textB) ? 1 : 0;
    }).appendTo('.news-layout-1');
});
```

Comment: Or sort the data first, then create them ("tomayto"/"tomahto").

Comment: When append moves elements it's one of those Jquery caveats that bites me in the butt every time. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can **delegate** the events instead of attaching them in the for loop.

When the click action is triggered, the event bubbles to the parent element ( body element in this case) to which the click handler is associated. You can then use `e.target` to get the exact `li` where the click happened.

```
  $('body').on('click', '.list-item', function(e) {
         alert($(e.target).data('i'));
    });

    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        var div = $('<div>', {
           id: i + "div",
           class: 'list-item ' + i,
           html: "Item #" + i
        });
        div.data('i', i);
        $('.news-layout-1').append(div);

       // move the click event out of the for loop
    }
```